# Is it normal for my router to have the activity on port 111?

Tags: tcp, router, nmap

What are typical results of nmap 198.168.1.1 for an average Joe? What would be a red flag?

PORT      STATE    SERVICE

111/tcp   filtered rpcbind

What does this mean in context and is it something to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, RCPBind is a service that enables file sharing over NFS,The rpcbind utility is a server that converts RPC program numbers into universal addresses. It must be running on the host to be able to make RPC calls on a server on that machine. When an RPC service is started, it tells rpcbind the address at which it is listening, and the RPC program numbers it is prepared to serve So if you have the use for file sharing, It's fine, otherwise unneeded and are a potential security risk.

You can disable them by running the following commands as root:

```
update-rc.d nfs-common disable
update-rc.d rpcbind disable
```

That will prevent them from starting at boot, but they will continue if already running until you reboot or stop them yourself.

And if you are looking to get into the system through this, There are lots of reading material available in the google.